# Working with a superclasses private member (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I have build a subclass from a class in Java that has private methods which I want to access in the subclass, I cannot change or edit the superclass. The problem is of course they are private. Suppose I have written the superclass by myself and there were certain reasons why these methods have to be private. I could copy the code in the subclass. But is there a better way (without producing so much lines of code) to get able to work with them when writing a subclass?

Comment: What are those certain reasons that restrict you from using `protected` instead of `private` methods?

Comment: With "Suppose I have written the superclass by myself..." I wanted to indicate that i have the code. The superclass is from a big library so changing the access is not possible.

Comment: No this statement, does not really indicate that you want to say that.

Comment: in such a case copy the method from super class, those methods are private for a reason. API developers wont hesitate to change or drop private  methods in upcoming releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring that your reasons for wanting to do this are potentially very bad (there's no contract for your usage of private variables, so there are no guarantees that they won't change, or disappear completely!) you could probably do what you want using reflection:

Using:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)

```
Class c = object.getClass();
Field field = c.getDeclaredField("somePrivateInstanceVariable");
field.setAccessible(true);
Object someValue = field.get(object);
```

I just want to emphasise that you should consider the reasons for doing this and decide against it! If you own the code that you are extending, consider if you should instead make the field `protected` instead of `private`. Remember, hooking into code you're not supposed to have access to breaks OOP principles (you're circumventing encapsulation) and there are no guarantees the code your application depends on won't disappear in an update to the library (so you're also locking yourself down to a fixed version of the lib).

Comment: I dont know anything about that reflection thing in java (it's on the TODO-list) but it looks amazingly anarchistic. But in my case i think its best to copy the private things in the subclass and get some inflexibility too. I guess inheriting from a given library superclass is not always what the developers of that library wanted. It nearly feels like hacking.

Comment: Agreed, you want to tread carefully. Sometimes, if I start heading down a path like this, I'll take a moment to step back and reconsider what it is that I'm actually trying to accomplish, and evaluate if the path I'm on is the best one after all.

Answer (score 0):

Make super class method's `protected`. It would be only accessible from `sub-class` and package.

`private` modifier's are only accessible with in class.

Comment: Non-private fields are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

So you tried with "extends" to inherit the methods from the superclass. And of course they are private, but you can use them in the sublass. Making them abstract would force you to rewrite every in private, i see no other option.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you should declare the private method as protected instead. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details on the subject.

Comment: The fact is, i dont have written the superclass. Im not allowed to change the declaration. I just wanted to indicate that I have the code.

Comment: The fact that you are not allowed to change the declaration wasn't clear in your question.

Since you said "Suppose I have written the superclass by myself and there were certain reasons why these methods have to be private" this would indicate that the method or methods only relate to the super class, in which case those methods should not be extended by nature.

Creating a new one in the subclass would be okay then, unless you really need the same method body verbatim! This means the design has to be re-considered!